# Time diff code is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I want to find total time spent by user on a page.

For that i am using following code but this is not working.
I am using jquery1.8. Please  see it.

```
var enterTime;
var endTime;
var diffTime; 
$(document).ready(function (e) {
            enterTime=e.timeStamp;

        });

        $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(f){
            endTime=f.timeStamp;
         diffTime=endTime-enterTime;
        alert(diffTime);
       });
```

Comment: What's not working? Are you getting any errors? Are you using a javascript debugger?

Comment: `alert(diffTime);` is undefined

Comment: You code doesn't work but this does - try it - http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/WMNKQ/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
var enterTime;
var endTime;
var diffTime; 
$(document).ready(function () {
            enterTime=new Date().getTime();
       });

       $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
            endTime=new Date().getTime();
            diffTime=endTime-enterTime;
       });
```

Please note that you cannot raise `alert()`s before closing the page in the way as described in your original post.

Comment: @user2302288 Thanks, and you're welcome. Enjoy your stay here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.on()` instead of shorthand:

```
$(document).on('ready',function (e) {
            enterTime=e.timeStamp;

        });
```